# Stream unstructured logs into structured format using jq

Tags: bash, docker, jq

I have a container with an entrypoint that runs a long-lived service.

`ENTRYPOINT /entrypoint.sh`

The service outputs logs to stdout and stderr in an unstructured format:

```
Informational message
An error
```

I need to wrap these logs in a JSON-structured format in order for them to be machine parsable, but I don't have control over the binary being run. The output should be like this:

```json
{
    "service": "foo",
    "msg": "Informational message",
    "severity": "stdout",
    "t": 1692606427758000000,
}
{
    "service": "foo",
    "msg": "An error",
    "severity": "stderr",
    "t": 1692606427772000000,
}
```

My idea was to create a wrapper entrypoint and then stream the output of the entrypoint into jq to generate the structure I want. I came up with this:

```
#! /bin/bash

exec /entrypoint.sh | jq -R 'split("\n")|{service:"foo", msg:.[0], severity:"stdout"}'
```

This works, but I want to separately handle stdout and stderr to change the `severity` field accordingly.

I tried using redirects but can't figure out how to make jq ingest from them, my attempt below results in nothing being output:

```
#! /bin/bash

exec /entrypoint.sh \
    >  >( jq -R 'split("\n")|{service:"foo", msg:.[0], severity:"stdout"}' ) \
    2> >( jq -R 'split("\n")|{service:"foo", msg:.[0], severity:"stderr"}' )
```

Any tips to how I can make jq behave how I want?

Comment: I wouldn't expect _nothing_. Are you sure your program doesn't buffer its output when stdout isn't a TTY? If that's the problem (and it's a likely one as this buffering is default libc behavior) it has a usual set of solutions already covered elsewhere in our knowledge base, not specific to jq.

Comment: Though there is a problem here -- you're feeding the output of your stderr jq into the stdout jq since redirections are processed in order left to right and the first one is done before the second one starts -- that's not a no-output problem.

Comment: Oh, that was not my intended behaviour. I wanted to redirect both `entrypoint.sh`'s stdout and stderr to `stdout`, but only after JSON-formatting them.

As for the buffering, I'm not sure, but if I change it to `exec /entrypoint.sh >  >( cat ) 2> >( cat )`

then I can see the outputs again, which is what made me think it was a jq ingestion issue.

Comment: Anyhow -- if it _is_ buffering, it's unhelpful that you aren't showing us the entry point script. There are sometimes specialized solutions -- for example if you're starting a Python program, the language provides its own environment variable to force stdout to be unbuffered.

Comment: Oh -- the cat test is useful. I'll want to look at this at a real computer, then; if it's unsolved in a few hours I'll be back.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark: You could prefix all lines with some marker indicating their provenance (e.g. `... > >(sed s/^/1/) 2> >(sed s/^/2/)`), so they can safely be unified into one stream, which then a single instance of jq can pick up on, taking the marker into consideration when generating its output.

Comment: Eh. Once they're split out, ordering no longer exists, and as long as you're okay with that (don't want to try to reassemble into a no-longer-existing order) the lines are short enough to fit in one `write()` syscall it's not so messy to unify; just want to be sure that jq is writing its output line-buffered rather than fully buffered.

Comment: Which _specific_ version of bash are you using? Some of them (I think post-4.3?) assign `$!` after creating a process substitution, so you can `wait` for that procsubst to exit. (Of course, that's harder to leverage when you're starting _two_ procsubsts in the same command).

Comment: The [unix.se] question [Using jq within pipe chain produces no output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/435413/using-jq-within-pipe-chain-produces-no-output) suggests `jq --unbuffered`. It's not documented in `--help` output, but it's genuinely there in jq 1.6, and prevents you from needing either `stdbuf -oL jq` or `docker run --tty`.

Comment: Thanks Charles, the `--unbuffered` tip fixed my nothing being output issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was found by @Charles Duffy, which was that we want to use jq with `--unbuffered` as my entrypoint is a long-running job. The outputs were being buffered and not appearing.

My fixed attempt from the original post is:

```bash
#! /bin/bash

exec /entrypoint.sh \
    2> >( jq -R --unbuffered 'split("\n")|{service:"foo", msg:.[0], severity:"stderr"}' > /dev/stderr) \
    >  >( jq -R --unbuffered 'split("\n")|{service:"foo", msg:.[0], severity:"stdout"}' > /dev/stdout)
```

Answer (score 2):

You redirect stdout to be processed by the first jq. The second jq inherits this redirection. This causes garbage.

Let's demo this.

```bash
jsonify() {
   local sev=$1
   shift
   jq -cR --arg sev "$sev" '
      split("\n") |
      { service: "foo", msg: .[0], severity: $sev }
   ' "$@"
}

driver() {
   echo "Message 1"
   echo "Message 2" >&2
   echo "Message 3" >&2
   echo "Message 4"
}

driver > >( jsonify stdout ) 2> >( jsonify stderr )
```

Output:

```
{"service":"foo","msg":"Message 1","severity":"stdout"}
{"service":"foo","msg":"Message 4","severity":"stdout"}
{"service":"foo","msg":"{\"service\":\"foo\",\"msg\":\"Message 2\",\"severity\":\"stderr\"}","severity":"stdout"}
{"service":"foo","msg":"{\"service\":\"foo\",\"msg\":\"Message 3\",\"severity\":\"stderr\"}","severity":"stdout"}
```

We can fix this by duplication stdout before it's redirection.

```bash
driver 3>&1 > >( jsonify stdout ) 2> >( jsonify stderr >&3 )
```

Output:

```
{"service":"foo","msg":"Message 2","severity":"stderr"}
{"service":"foo","msg":"Message 3","severity":"stderr"}
{"service":"foo","msg":"Message 1","severity":"stdout"}
{"service":"foo","msg":"Message 4","severity":"stdout"}
```

---

There's a second issue. The output of the jq processes can come after the command completes.

```
$ driver 3>&1 > >( jsonify stdout ) 2> >( jsonify stderr >&3 )

$ {"service":"foo","msg":"Message 2","severity":"stderr"}
{"service":"foo","msg":"Message 1","severity":"stdout"}
{"service":"foo","msg":"Message 3","severity":"stderr"}
{"service":"foo","msg":"Message 4","severity":"stdout"}
```

This is easily solved by adding a `wait`.

```bash
driver 3>&1 > >( jsonify stdout ) 2> >( jsonify stderr >&3 ); wait   # Fixed version
```

I don't know why you get *nothing*, but I presume one of these two problems is somehow responsible.

---

BUT! As nice as it is to put everything in one command, having two programs write to the same handle can't end well. Fixed:

```bash
out="$( mktemp )"
err="$( mktemp )"

driver >"$out" 2>"$err"

jsonify stdout "$out"
jsonify stderr "$err"

rm "$out" "$err"
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it's helpful to know that sending everything to stdout is a bad idea. I will change that going forward and keep stdout going to stdout and stderr going to stderr.

However, I tried incorporating your solution to my entrypoint and it didn't work and there's no output.

Comment: Also, the edited solution also won't work because I `exec` my entrypoint. My IDE's bash script checker says: `Remove "exec " if script should continue after this command.
See SC2093.`. I assume the calls to `jsonify` will never be reached.

Comment: Greatly simplified the single-command solution. /// Correct, you can't use `exec` in the bottom version.

Comment: Thanks ikegami. I tried that simplified version but sadly it still outputs nothing to the terminal.

This command ended up working for me:
`exec /entrypoint.sh > >(sed s/^/stdout\;/) 2> >(sed s/^/stderr\;/) | jq -c -R 'split("\n")[0]|split(";")|{service:"foo", msg:.[1], severity:.[0]}'`

But now I realise I shouldn't be combing everything from stderr and stdout into a single stream, so think this approach is wrong too.

Comment: What you posted doesn't work. It suffers from the same double-processing as the original. (Two of the messages are `{"service":"foo","msg":"stderr","severity":"stdout"}`)

Comment: Updated my answer to provide a solution to a second issue.

Comment: Thanks once again for the updated answer, sadly adding the `; wait` did not fix the empty output issue. The warning: `Remove "exec " if script should continue after this command.` could be relevant to why this isn't working.

Comment: Do you see any `exec` in my code? Again, stop using `exec` for anything but the last command

Comment: Also, went back to using fd 3. The "simpler solution" fails when jq writes to stderr.

Comment: Thanks once again for the updated answer, sadly adding the `; wait` did not fix the empty output issue. The warning: `Remove "exec " if script should continue after this command.` could be relevant to why this isn't working.

I tried changing it to `./entrypoint.sh 2> >( jsonify stderr ) > >( jsonify stdout ); exec wait` or `./entrypoint.sh 2> >( jsonify stderr ) > >( jsonify stdout ); wait` incase either of these would be better, but neither solved the issue.

Comment: FWIW, it should be no `exec` at all when you use `wait`.

Comment: @OscarVanL BTW, to be very clear, the `wait` approach doesn't make jq write output _immediately_, it just tells the docker container not to exit before it waits for jq to finish. If you're killing the container, vs the entrypoint exiting on its own, then it won't help -- so a lot of this depends on exactly how one is testing.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Exactly. I'm guessing they're getting no output because the container is killed before jq can output. If so, the `wait` will fix the problem. As soon as they stop using `exec`!

Comment: Depends on how they're killing it! If the entrypoint script being wrapped exits, then the parent shell exits, then the rest of the cgroup gets killed, the `wait` will help. If the OP is using something like `docker kill` that kills the whole cgroup at once (and honestly, I have no idea if ctrl+c on a `docker run` does the same thing), then the shell won't get a chance to wait for jq to flush.

Comment: @Charles Duffy, I'm referring to existing normally. I'm assuming the container shuts down when the program ends? That's before jq finishes.

Comment: @ikegami, right, but a lot of Docker entrypoints are for long-running servers, so whether "the program ends" at all without the OP explicitly terminating it is an open question; so one needs to worry about ordering within that terminations.

Comment: @Charles Duffy, Ah, your take is that the OP isn't waiting for the command to complete. Make sense to not see output then, yeah. And "unbuffering" all three programs would solve that.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that point of confusion up Charles, apologies ikegami I should have been clearer, this service runs forever and the command never “completes” (until it receives SIGTERM and gets restarted when I redeploy it). Thank you both for the help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to redirect stderr before stdout.

If you want to see output when you `docker run`, add `--tty`. Or use `stdbuf -oL` (or better `jq --unbuffered`) before `jq` as suggested by @CharlesDuffy

Dockerfile ==>

```
FROM ubuntu
ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y jq
WORKDIR /tmp
COPY entrypoint.sh entrypoint2.sh /tmp/
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh entrypoint2.sh
ENTRYPOINT ./entrypoint2.sh
```

entrypoint.sh ==>

```
#!/bin/bash
c=0
while sleep 1; do
    ((c=1-c)) && date || date >&2
done
```

entrypoint2.sh ==>

```
#!/bin/bash
./entrypoint.sh \
   2> >( jq -R '{service:"foo", msg:., severity:"stderr"}' ) \
    > >( jq -R '{service:"foo", msg:., severity:"stdout"}' )
```

Run the whole thing with :

```
docker build -t test . && docker run --tty --rm --name test test
```

Comment: Probably should be able to work around the need for `--tty`. Does using `stdbuf -oL` to wrap `jq` help?

Comment: @Philippe, Re "*It seems you need to redirect stderr before stdout.*", I had that as my solution for while, but that just shifts the problem from stdout to stderr (i.e. it goes from misbehaving when the second jq writes to stdout to misbehaving when the second jq writes to stderr). That's why a third handle is needed.

Comment: (...of course, even line-buffered content can still be lost in shutdown if one loses the race condition, so a `wait` remains best practice regardless, but switching to line buffering will decrease the window for the amount of data thrown out of the race is lost; it's an improvement no matter what, even if the `--tty` approach is somewhat crude).

Comment: Re "*that's a fairly rare case and a tolerable one for a human reader to figure out.*", Why tolerate when it's easy to do right? `./entrypoint.sh 3>&1 > >( ... ) 2> >( ... >&3 )`. (And since when is converting error logs to JSON done for human readers??)

Comment: True, but it's a human who'll be reading whatever log aggregator the JSON is thrown into, and if there's a jq malfunction it'll be specifically  a human who knows JSON that's escalated to for fixing. :)

Comment: @Philippe, ...alternately, would you consider `jq --unbuffered` a good enough solution to make the primary showcased suggestion instead of an aside?

Answer (score 1):

Using [TXR](https://nongnu.org/txr) Lisp:

```
$ txr -e '(whilet ((ln (get-line)))
            (put-jsonl #J^{"service":"foo", "msg":~ln,
                           "severity":"sdout", "t":~(* 1,000,000.0 (time))}))'
foo
{"msg":"foo","service":"foo","t":1.692631417e15,"severity":"sdout"}
foo"bar
{"msg":"foo\"bar","service":"foo","t":1.692631419e15,"severity":"sdout"}
[Ctrl-D][Enter]
$
```